# Same Row_Number for Same Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to have row numbering where the ROW_NUMBER is the same for same value column:  MFGPN (Same MFGPN will always be in sequence).  I also need to maintain the original sequence by No.

Here's my table

```
No     MFGPN
1      Z363700Z01
2      Z363700Z01
3      0119-960-1
4      1A3F1-0503-01
```

I tried using RANK() to achieve the desired but am running into trouble.

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MFGPN) As [Item], MFGPN FROM Table1 ORDER BY [No] ASC
```

RESULT

```
Item   MFGPN           Desired Result
3      Z363700Z01            1
3      Z363700Z01            1
1      0119-960-1            2
2      1A3F1-0503-01         3
```

Appreciate you guys' expert advise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` window function instead of `RANK`. `Rank` will skip the sequence when there is a repetition of data `Dense_Rank` will not.

```
SELECT MFGPN,
        Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY m_no) as [Desired Result]
FROM   (SELECT no,
                MFGPN,
                Min(no)OVER(partition BY MFGPN) AS m_no
        FROM   (VALUES (1,'Z363700Z01' ),
                        (2,'Z363700Z01' ),
                        (3,'0119-960-1' ),
                        (4,'1A3F1-0503-01')) tc (no, MFGPN))a
```

If `no` is not unique then change `DENSE_RANK` to

```
Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY m_no,MFGPN)
```

**Result :**

```
+---------------+----------------+
|     MFGPN     | Desired Result |
+---------------+----------------+
| Z363700Z01    |              1 |
| Z363700Z01    |              1 |
| 0119-960-1    |              2 |
| 1A3F1-0503-01 |              3 |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Prdp.  I don't get it though.  I'm still getting 3, 3, 1, 2 with DENSE_RANK.  I need it to be 1, 1, 2, 3

Comment: @Bobbit - How you want to define the order ? Why `Z363700Z01` should be `1` and `1A3F1-0503-01` should be `3` ?

Comment: Order by `[No]`.  Exactly as the table I presented with 'Desired Result'

Comment: `ORDER BY m_no` will be enough

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - What if the `no` is repeated for another `MFGPN`

Comment: Seems like a unique value for the whole set and not per MFGPN and if it wasn't you couldn't  use it to keep the order

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - Initially even I didn't add `MFGPN` in `Dense_rank`. Updated my post accordingly

Comment: @Prdp - Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should partition the results by `mfgpn` so that rows with the same `mfgpn` get the same rank and order by the `no`. Additionally, using `dense_rank` will ensure you don't "skip" any ranks:

```
SELECT   DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [mfgpn] ORDER BY [no]) As [Item], 
         [mfgpm] 
FROM     Table1 
ORDER BY [No] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select      sum(case when MFGPN = prev_MFGPN then 0 else 1 end) over (order by No)  as item
           ,MFGPN

from       (SELECT      lag(MFGPN) over (order by [No]) as prev_MFGPN   
                       ,[No]
                       ,MFGPN 
            FROM        Table1 
            ) t

ORDER BY    [No] ASC
```

---

```
+------+---------------+
| item | MFGPN         |
+------+---------------+
| 1    | Z363700Z01    |
+------+---------------+
| 1    | Z363700Z01    |
+------+---------------+
| 2    | 0119-960-1    |
+------+---------------+
| 3    | 1A3F1-0503-01 |
+------+---------------+
```

Comment: This is what you have requested

Comment: `'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.` I got this. Sorry I should've pointed out I'm using 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can try below snippet. DENSE_RANK() a explained above s the best approach in this case.

```
    SELECT a.*,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MFGPN DESC) RN
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 AS no, 'Z363700Z01' AS mfgpn FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS no, 'Z363700Z01' AS mfgpn FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 AS no, '0119-960-1' AS mfgpn FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 AS no, '1A3F1-0503-01' AS MFGPN FROM dual
      )a;

-------------------------------OUTPUT-------------------------------------------
NO  MFGPN           RN
1   Z363700Z01      1
2   Z363700Z01      1
4   1A3F1-0503-01   2
3   0119-960-1      3

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY IT**: I think it's more simple and flexible to use `join` and compare value to get the desired output as below:

```
SELECT p.MFGPN,
       Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN p.MFGPN = tp.MFGPN THEN tp.num ELSE p.num END) AS [Desired Result]
FROM tmp_option p
LEFT JOIN tmp_option tp ON tp.num+1 = p.num
ORDER BY p.num ASC
```